# Can't run file in Netbeans using SHIFT + F6

Tags: java, netbeans

Why Netbeans does have a lot of bugs now. I can`t use the shift + f6 to run my file :( However if I use the run button in the toggle button it takes a lot of time. Hope you help me guys

[image]

Comment: Is that class runnable to begin with?

Comment: yes sir it`s working